# How can I group and name the incoming values ​in the request according to the standards in the config-repo with Springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, algorithm, code-cleanup

In the request, I will receive a Solr-name field of type List. I need to group by solr-name name. For example, gender_s, age_f and job_s came. If these three come, I have to assign them as demographics. But I don't want to do this with an ugly if else code block. How can I group this information cleanly? My second question is that I want to parse the fields containing subrules in the same way and show them with view name. How can I do it with a clean code?

**My config-repo :**

```
project.search.categories:
  sms:
    view-name: Sms
    rules:
      sms:
        view-name: operator tarafindan atilan aylik atilan sms sayisi
        solr-name: sms_count_f
        view-type: NUMERIC
        solr-type: BIGINT
        min-value: 0
        max-value: 150
        max-range: 50  
  demography:
    view-name: Demografi
    rules:
      gender:
        view-name: Cinsiyet
        solr-name: gender_s
        view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
        solr-type: STRING
      age:
        view-name: Yas
        solr-name: age_f
        view-type: NUMERIC
        solr-type: BIGINT
        min-value: 0
        max-value: 150
        max-range: 50
      job:
        view-name: Meslek
        solr-name: job_s
        view-type: MULTI_SELECT
        solr-type: STRING
        values: JOBS
      citizenship:
        view-name: Uyruk
        solr-name: citizenship_s
        view-type: MULTI_SELECT
        solr-type: STRING
        values: ROAMING_COUNTRY 
  interest:
    view-name: Ilgi Alanlari
    rules:
      betting:
        view-name: Spor Bahisleri ile ilgilenen
        solr-name: betting__sports_interest_f
        view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
        solr-type: TINYINT
        values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
      career:
        view-name: Kariyer
        solr-name: career_interest_f
        view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
        solr-type: TINYINT
        values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
      coupons:
        view-name: \u0130ndirimler ile ilgilenen
        solr-name: coupons__discount_interest_f
        view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
        solr-type: TINYINT
        values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
      device_site:
        view-name: Teknoloji ile ilgilenen
        solr-name: device_site__technology_interest_f
        view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
        solr-type: TINYINT
        values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
      e-commerce:
        view-name: E-ticaret ile ilgilenen
        solr-name: ecommerce_interest_f
        view-type: MULTISELECT_TINYINT
        solr-type: TINYINT
        values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
        subrules:
          home_furniture:
            view-name: Ev dekorasyonu ile ilgilenen
            solr-name: ecommerce__home_furniture_interest_f
            view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
            solr-type: TINYINT
            values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
          clothing:
            view-name: Tekstil ile ilgilenen
            solr-name: ecommerce__clothing_interest_f
            view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
            solr-type: TINYINT
            values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
          automobiles:
            view-name: Otomobil ile ilgilenen
            solr-name: ecommerce__automobiles_interest_f
            view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
            solr-type: TINYINT
            values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
          market_place:
            view-name: Online Market Place Al\u0131sveris ile ilgilenen
            solr-name: ecommerce__market_place_interest_f
            view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
            solr-type: TINYINT
            values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
          sports:
            view-name: Spor Al\u0131\u015fveri\u015fi ile ilgilenen
            solr-name: ecommerce__sports_interest_f
            view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
            solr-type: TINYINT
            values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
          technology:
            view-name: Teknoloji Al\u0131\u015fveri\u015fi ile ilgilenen
            solr-name: ecommerce__technology_interest_f
            view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
            solr-type: TINYINT
            values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
          books:
            view-name: Kitap Al\u0131\u015fverisi ile ilgilenen
            solr-name: ecommerce__books_interest_f
            view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
            solr-type: TINYINT
            values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
          kids:
            view-name: \u00c7ocuk i\u00e7in Al\u0131\u015fveri\u015f yapan
            solr-name: ecommerce__kids_interest_f
            view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
            solr-type: TINYINT
            values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
          comparison:
            view-name: Fiyat Kar\u015f\u0131la\u015ft\u0131rma # convert
            solr-name: ecommerce__comparison_interest_f
            view-type: SINGLE_SELECT
            solr-type: TINYINT
            values: 1@Evet, 0@Hay\u0131r
```

I defined and assigned it in the config repo, and use my microservices @Value("${project.....) annotation but there is too much data and I think there may be a better solution that I can show with view-name without using if else. I really need your help, thank you.